# Is there a way to fit a border into a ListView Item?

Tags: c#, wpf

I prepared a table view with the `ListView` method.

Codes here :

```
 <Grid>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <ListView x:Name="ListViewTableBorder" ItemsSource="{Binding TableName}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Style="{StaticResource sales_border}">
                        <TextBlock Name="tablename" Text="{Binding tablename}" MinHeight="100" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontSize="20"/>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Rows="5"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        </ListView>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Since I divide the screen into 5 columns, the `ListViewItems` automatically adjust the width. What can I do to make the borders inside the `ListViewItems` populate?

Border Style here :

```
 <Style x:Key="sales_border" TargetType="Border">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#0a7d38"/>
        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="8"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,5,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#00d052"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Hi! I'm not sure what your exact problem is: is your listview empty? does it have a width of 0 and you want its width to be wider? I mean, what is your expected output and how is it different from what you currently have?

Comment: I mean, I want the ListViewItem size to match the size of the border inside it.

Comment: I strongly recommend providing a minimal reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  Edit your question to make it 100% clear what is happening and how that differs from what you want to happen. Think in terms of people looking at your question. They don't need to answer it. Make it easy for them to paste in code and see it not working and they are much more likely to try and help. Make it difficult and they will more likely just do their own work. Or tell you that they don't understand exactly what you're asking, aren't going to try and guess.

Comment: Sorry for my English. What I would like to say : Filling the border into the listview item.